# Error de ffmpeg con Whisper para transcripción

Tags: python, ffmpeg

estoy tratando de usar whisper para una transcripcion de audio y no puedo encontrar una solución a este error, creo que tiene que ver con ffmpeg, que ya tengo instalado en el venv en el que estoy, ffmpeg-python Version: 0.2.0. Cualquier comentario se agradece!

El código que estoy ejecutando:

```
model = whisper.load_model('small')
result = model.transcribe('tmp.mp4')

print(result['text'])
```

El error que estoy obteniendo:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\TFM\prueba.py", line 14, in <module>
    result = model.transcribe('tmp.mp4')
  File "C:\Users\user\TFM\lib\site-packages\whisper\transcribe.py", line 121, in transcribe
    mel = log_mel_spectrogram(audio, padding=N_SAMPLES)
  File "C:\Users\user\TFM\lib\site-packages\whisper\audio.py", line 140, in log_mel_spectrogram
    audio = load_audio(audio)
  File "C:\Users\user\TFM\lib\site-packages\whisper\audio.py", line 59, in load_audio
    out = run(cmd, capture_output=True, check=True).stdout
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 503, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 1456, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
```

Comment: El error es sobre la ruta del audio

Comment: Quieres hacer audio y le mandas un video. Extrae el audio del video e intenta de nuevo. Saludos.